# CSS "nested" If - add attribute to different class

Tags: css, user-interface, css-selectors

I have this selector:

```
.ui-widget-overlay
{
    background: #262b33;
    opacity: .70;
    filter: Alpha(Opacity=70);
}
```

I want to have the ability to do something like that:

```
.ui-widget-overlay
{
    background: #262b33;
    opacity: .70;
    filter: Alpha(Opacity=70);

    .container: 
    {
        -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
    }

}
```

Which means, If this selector is active, add this attribute to container .

Is that possible? Or should I take the JS way?

Comment: is container the parent?

Comment: Yes, it's the parent div

Comment: I'd use jquery for this. As far as i know, there is no way to select a parent afterwards? http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Answer (score 1):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/6ssD3/)**

You can use the attribute selector like

```
div[class="ui-widget-overlay"] .container {....}
```

html /* for example */

```
<div class="ui-widget-overlay">Test
    <div class="container">Container</div>
</div>
```

css

```
.ui-widget-overlay {
    background: #262b33;
    opacity: .70;
    filter: Alpha(Opacity=70);
}
div[class="ui-widget-overlay"] .container {
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
    color: red; /* added to see a visible change */
}
```

Comment: My situation is this: http://jsfiddle.net/6ssD3/4/ - I need to have apply blur on container.

Comment: you want to apply `-webkit-filter: blur(5px);` to container or test?

Comment: to container if ui-widget-overlay is applied.

Comment: There is no parent selector in css yet, you need to use jquery for that.

Answer (score 0):

Add one more class and set it to both `.container` and `.ui-widget-overlay` -

```
.ui-widget-overlay.nowActive {
    background: #262b33;
    opacity: .70;
    filter: Alpha(Opacity=70);
}

.container.nowActive  {
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
}
```

with JS/jQuery add/remove the `.nowActice` when it required  .

In jQuery it's  - [.addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.
http://jsfiddle.net/3p3j9/4/

```
.test1
{
    background:yellow;
    font-family:Arial;
}

.test1 > .test2
{
    background:cyan;
}
```

The container will apply the design only if it is inside the main container.

```
<div class='test1'>
    test12345
    <div class='test2'>
        test123
    </div>
</div>
<div class='test2'>
    test1234567
</div>
```